# Mimic client request

Tags: httprequest

I have a server running on my machine. I want to send a request to the server using different IP address to test a web application. I only have the machine on which the server is installed. I have been testing as a single user but now I would like to let the server think that the request is coming from a different ip address even though it is from the same machine. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: can you tell us which language do you use ?

Comment: cause you could simply use a Proxy to mimic the request from another computer

Comment: If you are using c# you could use the HttpClient and apply a proxy into it, or if you just want to use firefox you might be able to set a proxy and access your webapplication from there.

Comment: I have developed a j2ee app. I wanted to send request to the server which is on my machine as different client from that very same machine. Can I use proxy to do that? If so can you refer me to an article?

Comment: You could simply apply a proxy to your browser so you can access your own website but from another IP

Comment: i will post an answer now

Comment: The machine is not connected to internet. Will it still work?

Comment: Which machine is not connected, i mean can you just use the machine that you are talking to me from ?

Comment: I can use the machine. But it is a simple client. Not connected to any network. It has a Apache server installed with the web application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the 2 solutions that might be possible in your situation

1- To change the ip address :

- Pick an ip from the free proxies here: http://www.freeproxylists.net/
- And enter the info in firefox just like this page says:
  http://www.wikihow.com/Enter-Proxy-Settings-in-Firefox
- `Note: You may pick a proxy with port 80.`
- Then you are good to go...

2- Or you might use a `Virtual Machine` installed on the same computer as the server and access the website right from it but beware not to use bridged connection.

Comment: Does't this process need the machine to be connected to internet. My machine is not connected to any network. It is a test machine and I need to send request to the server from the same machine as different ip address like it came over a another computer.

Comment: @infestation, why do you need to send the request from the same isolated machine ?, why not just use a network connected machine just for the sake of using the proxy and enter your local network up to access it from the browser with the proxy enabled.

Comment: i am not whether the target machine needs to be connected to the internet though. Just give it a try. If not working just put your apache server online and access it normally. Because as far as i know there is no way you can access the server from the same machine which is not connected to the internet using another ip address.

Comment: Well, that is it then. The virtual machine thing sounds good way. Let me try it your way.